# Python почему происходит AttributeError в цикле while?

Tags: python

```
import imaplib
import email

def main():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login('********@gmail.com', '********')
    mail.list()
    while(True):
        # Ниже строка из-за которой ошибка!
        mail.select("inbox")  # Подключаемся к папке "входящие".
        result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

        ids = data[0]  # Получаем сроку номеров писем
        id_list = ids.split()  # Разделяем ID писем
        latest_email_id = id_list[-1]  # Берем последний ID

        result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")  # Получаем тело письма (RFC822) для данного ID

        raw_email = data[0][1]  # Тело письма в необработанном виде
        # включает в себя заголовки и альтернативные полезные нагрузки


        mail = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)

        a = mail.get_payload()[ 0 ].get_payload(decode=True)
        print(a.decode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Почему срабатыавет `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'select'`?
При этом программа нормально продолжает работать и даже выводит последнее полученное на почту письмо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mail = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)

После первой итерации вы перезаписывете переменную mail

А она должна быть хэндлером для imap

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')